# Export birt reports (Using birt-viewer) directly to excel (or any) format

Tags: excel, url, birt

I have birt-viewer running on apache tomcat.
I thought there might be an option to use a URL parameter that will directly export the report to XLS format and send it to the user.

I couldn't find a way to do that. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it.
add "&__format=xls" to url.